How do I avoid redeclarations of a type
I have a collection of protobuf files (which I can't modify) in which I am using to create a static library.
I also have an additional library that is deep in the app layer of my tech stack (that I can't modify either :( ) that has a conflict - an enum definition with the exact same name. In the include order the header in the app layer always seems to be compiled first, so by the time I import the protobuf type, say 'TypeA' by including the generated protobuf header, I get a redefinition error.
I'm struggling massively with how I get around this. I know a bad practice would be to include the header of the generated protobuf in a namespace like:
namespace WrapperNamespace {

#include "TypeAMsg.pb.h"

}

But that won't work with all the std:: namespace stuff within generated protobuf files.
I'm struggling as how to get this to work if possible at all.
The library I create of the generated protobufs is a static library, which I then include into the BaseLibrary, which is also a static library.
I was trying to wrap my head around how that could workaround the symbol generation, but not sure it matters. As soon as in the BaseLibrary, I include "TypeAMsg.pb.h", I'll see that error again.
Is there a workaround? Is there someway I can make an intermediate library that behaves like a wrapper? I don't care if all my types from the generated protobufs library are all only accessible with a namespace.. I guess that seems like the point of namespaces in general!
Obviously if I could just manipulate the protobuf definitions or the app layer header itself, this would be no problem. But I can't...so I'm trying to find a viable workaround.
Thanks in advance!

Place your protobuf messages into Packages

If a .proto file contains a package declaration, the entire contents of the file will be placed in a corresponding C++ namespace. For example, given the package declaration:
package foo.bar;

All declarations in the file will reside in the foo::bar namespace.

